# MX record (Godaddy) How do I get contact form to send via shared hosting, but also recieve emails on my workspace email?

Tags: php, dns, phpmailer, mx-record

Sorry for the complicated title, I myself am not too sure what the problem is but essentially Godaddy only allows for 1 type of MX record - either mail.yourdomain.com or smtp.secureserver.net. They told me in order to have my php mail() contact form to work, I need to have mail.yourdomain.com as the MX. However, I also want to have a seperate email to receive incoming emails and that requires the smtp.secureserver.net as the MX entry.

My question is is there any way to get these two to work simultaneously?

Basically I want my server to send the contact form email on my site, while at the same time I receive emails in my Godaddy Workspace email client.

Comment: did you tried to send an email like `mail("your@email.com", "My Subject", "My text");`?

Answer (score 0):

For outbound email you need to use GoDaddy's `secureserver.net` servers (covered many times on here, and in PHPMailer docs), but that has no bearing on inbound mail or your MX records. They are entirely independent, so I don't see any reason  why your outbound server should have any bearing on what you use for outbound.

You can have multiple MX records, but you can't choose which gets used other than via priority field in your DNS, but that's not a reliable approach.

Comment: hmm the godaddy support agent told me that I can ONLY have either mail.mydomain.com OR secureserver.net. He said mail.mydomain.com is used for my server to send mail properly while secureserver.net is used for my godaddy workspace email to work and receive / send emails properly from the Godaddy workspace email client